# Querying database based on natural language input

Tags: mysql, solr, elasticsearch, lucene, nlp

I am looking to build a system where I can ask my database questions in a natural language format and it returns the appropriate result. For example:

```
Database contains winners of all Football world cups.
My Search Query: Who was the winner in 2014
Result: Germany
```

Basically I want a way of understanding that what my query essentially meant was winner = 2014 and I ask the database to return the rows where winner = 2014.

What is the most efficient way of doing this. This was just an example but I need a more dynamic way of doing this. I also want to know what databases support Natural Language Processing as this looks like a classic NLP problem. How should I be approaching this problem. Which databases support such NLP querying? I don't have any experience in NLP so I am really looking for leads more than anything else. Is ElasticSearch/Solr/Lucene something that I should be looking into? Would really appreciate any kind of input.

Comment: The subject of natural language search for querying a data is (in my opinion) way too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  I would suggest you start by learning the basics of NLP and some of the history of natural language products for interfacing to databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Exactly what led me to post here. I did try to look for sources but there are so many different resources and opinions available that I got really confused. More than a solution, I am looking for some leads in order to be able to filter out some of the options and look in the right direction. Would really be grateful if you could provide me with some.

Comment: @VinayGaba Did you find a solution or how did you build it.